# Set javascript variable on php include

Tags: javascript, php

I have an html with several links sending a Get request to a `Handler.php` file, like

```
<a href="Handler?Node=FirstGroup"><div class="MyClass">First Group</div></a>
<a href="Handler?Node=SecondGroup"><div class="MyClass">Second Group</div></a>
```

and then the `Handler.php` sends the request back, using `include`:

```
if(isset($_GET['Node'])) {
    $Node=$_GET['Node'];
    if ($Node=="FirstGroup"){
        include 'Header.php';
        include '1MainTitle.php';
        include '2Selector.php';
        include '3FirstGroup.php';
        include 'xfoot.php';
    }
    elseif ($Node=="SecondGroup"){
        include 'Header.php';
        include '1MainTitle.php';
        include '2Selector.php';
        include '3SecondGroup.php';
        include 'xfoot.php';
    }
}
```

My problem lies in `Header.php`. Although I see the javascript in the browser (with F12), inspector show the warning `TypeError: slides[(slideIndex - 1)] is undefined`, and first slide is not showing up (the script is for showing several photos, one after the other).

My `Header.php` file is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>The Title</title>
    <link href="../Files/EB.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="icon" href="../Files/Images/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
```

Note that `slideIndex` is defined in the script.

My question is: browser "reads" javascript after loading it from php include?

Comment: You could put the start of the slider action in a document.ready function.

Comment: Thats it! Solved, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In your `showSlides` function `slideIndex` does not get defined in all cases.

It gets defined where `n > slides.length`.

It also gets defined where `n < 1`.

Otherwise, it is undefined.

In the code above you pass `n` in to the function as `1`, and so if there are more than 1 slide, `slideIndex` remains undefined.

Comment: Maybe I should check deeper the code. Anyway the problem was solved inserting `slideIndex = 1;` inside `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {}`. And now all images are being displayed properly. Thanks!